# Good voice over software?

Tags: sound, sound-effects-recording, voice-over, voice-manipulation, suggestion

I am a Noob and trying to make my first video using quicktime screen recording and iMovies. Somewhere in the video, I need the voice of a child. It is not possible for me to get a real child to record.

Can you please suggest some good software that can take an adult female voice and can modify it to sound like that of a child? I am on MAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Garage Band or Logic (I'm a Windows Cubase user), but your best bet is to simply record a child, but I'm assuming that's not an option. You can use just about any DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) to record your voice and using a blend of pitch shifting (shifting the lead vocal an octave or two down) and combining the newly modified clip with the original one. Also look into vocoders.